# What is a regex that would match using the word نيك alone and not when combined with other words like الهندسة الميكانيكية

Tags: python, regex

I have tried **\bنيك\b** but this does not seem to work.

Examples would be:
نيك  should MATCH

الهندسة الميكا**نيك**ية should NOT MATCH

نيك  نيك  نيك  should MATCH

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: the word when used alone is a bad word. i wanted to know how the regex would result a match if the word نيك was used alone. what is the regex match for نيك  but not نيك  combined with other words before and after.

Comment: look into word boundaries (`\b`) and UTF-8 capabilities (the `re.U` flag)

Answer (score 0):

Reasoning about the RegExp pattern using English words was a more straightforward way for me to go about this.

I have used a pattern that combines negative lookahead assertion with positive lookahead assertion to exclude specific matching patterns.

You can replace `hello` with `نيك` in the given pattern below to test against words.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"""
(?=(?![\w\s]+)) # don't match next group when word/space is before it
(hello[\s]?)+   # match hello with optional space repeatedly
|               # or
(hello[\s]?)+   # match hello with optional space repeatedly
(?=(?![\w\s]+)) # don't match previous group when word/space is after it
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Testing  cases

```
>>> case1 = 'hello'
>>> case2 = 'hello world'
>>> case3 = 'world hello'
>>> case4 = 'ehlo world hello'
>>> case5 = 'hello hello hello'

>>> re.match(pattern, case1)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='hello'>
>>> re.match(pattern, case2)

>>> re.match(pattern, case3)

>>> re.match(pattern, case4)

>>> re.match(pattern, case5)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='hello hello hello'>
```

Comment: Thank you Oluwafemi, i think this has pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

If my understanding is right, just use str.count() module.